# Problems with OnClickListener

Tags: java, android, onclick

Hey am new to android , i just want to handle a click event , but i got problems ...thi sis my code:

```
package karim.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class TestActivity extends Activity implements android.view.View.OnClickListener {


    private Button b1;


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        b1 = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b1.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {



    }
```

and i got this error :

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The method onClick(View) of type TestActivity must override a superclass method TestActivity.java   /Test/src/karim/test    line 33 Java Problem
```

can you please tell me whats wrong ????

**Please Be specific !!**

Comment: do check this link
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that you're compiling with a Java 5 compiler (or Java 5 compiler settings in the IDE). In Java 5, `@Override` was only usable on a method overriding a method of a *class*, not an interface. It was extended to interface method overriding in Java 6.

Change the compiler version, or remove the `@Override` annotation on the `onClick` method.

Comment: Yes, but look at your compilation preferences. See @anujprashar's answer

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity{


    private Button b1;


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        b1 = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

    }
```

or in your case

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity implements android.view.View.OnClickListener {


    private Button b1;


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        b1 = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b1.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v==b1)
    {
       //button logic
    }

    }
```

Comment: If the OP's code doesn't compile, this code won't compile either.

Comment: in your first case no need to add the onclicklistener for implements

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to have your Activity class implement OnClickListener.  Get rid of that.   You just need to define the listener and assign it to your button.  Take a look at the official android docs:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html

Answer (score 0):

As an extension to "JB Nizet" answer:

The neatest way to handle `onClick`-events is (in my opinion) to add the [`onClick`-attribute](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#onClick) to the XML-Layout definition.

```
<Button android:text="Click Me!"
  android:onClick="doSomething"
/>
```

In your java-code:

```
public void doSomething(View v){
  // Do stuff here
}
```

This way, you can define a single method for every single `onClick`-event. This is available since API-Level 4 which corresponds to Android 1.6

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using compiler below java 6 for your project in eclipse. Right click on your project, go to properties-->Java compiler. Make sure you have 1.6 selected in compiler compliance field.